# Angular Reactive Froms, Getting Pristine of nested control

Tags: angular, forms, reactive

I am creating a fairly simple nested form.

Form Group > Form Array > Form Group > Controls

In the html I am trying to add a Remove button, but I want to only show when the last item is not pristine or empty.

That button css switch should look something like this...
[class.d-none]="itemName.pristine && itemName == '' && isLast" based on everything I can find on google, but I am getting an error.

Error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pristine' of undefined`

html

```
<div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of wishlistForm.get('items').controls; let i = index; last as isLast;" class="mb-4">
<div class="form-row" [formGroupName]="i">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemName" formControlName="itemName" placeholder="Enter your gift ideas here">
    <button type="button" [class.d-none]="itemName.pristine" class="close m-1" aria-label="Close btn-danger" (click)="remove(i)">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" formControlName="itemUrl">
</div>
```

ts

```
wishlistForm = this.fb.group({
    items: this.fb.array([])
});

createItemFields(name = "", url = "", uid = ""): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        itemName: [name],
        itemUrl: [url],
        itemUid: [uid]
    })
}

get items() {
    return this.wishlistForm.get('items') as FormArray;
}

addItem(name = "", url = "", uid = "") {
    this.items.push(this.createItemFields(name, url, uid));
}
```

Comment: You need to use this: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

wishlistForm.get('items').controls[i].get('itemName').pristine